# Django filter against Multiple Item QuerySets

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have two Model's which are related with a ForeignKey field.
Let's call these objects Event and EventRegistration.

I can easily, for example, do this:

```
EventRegistration.objects.filter(event=Event.objects.get(name="Some Event"))
```

But, I cannot do something like this:

```
EventRegistration.objects.filter(event=Event.objects.all())
```

I know this is a contrived example, but is there a way to filter against whole QuerySets in a similar way to the second line of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
EventRegistration.objects.filter(event__in=Event.objects.all())
```

Comment: Ok, this was just me being really stupid this morning.- Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I don't find the answer to this... do you know if that query use the Event.objects.all() is used as select into que query or is coverted to list to use the ids? or better Event.objects.all().values('id') if is as select